# To notify collection changed while adding item to IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My requirement is item should be added in IEnumerable collection and should trigger Collection changed event while item added/removed from IEnumerable collection.

Using Reflection I have try to add new item in IEnumarable collection and I tried the below scenario but could not notify collection changed while new item added in IEnumarable collection,Is any other solution for this.

Tried below one,IEnumarable collection not get updated.

```
((IEnumerable<object>)ItemsSource).ToList().Add(NewItemsSourceAppointment);
```

Tried below one,IEnumarable collection updated but not trigger collection changed event.

```
ItemsSource = ((IEnumerable<object>)ItemsSource).Concat(new[] { NewItemsSourceAppointment });
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't have an `Add` method.  Can you not just use the `ObservableCollection` that is made for this?

Comment: What is stored in `ItemsSource`? If it was initialized using `ObservableCollection<SomeType>`, then use type casting: `((ObservableCollection<SomeType>)ItemsSource).Add(new SomeType())`.

Comment: Collection change notification isn't some magic that you can retrospectively add to anything you like. `IEnumerable` is an interface, it's the implementation of that interface that is responsible for adding functionality like change notification.

Comment: `((ICollection<SomeType>)ItemsSource).Add(NewItemsSourceAppointment)` should work for every modifyable collection. When the actual collection type implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the `CollectionChanged` event will be fired. Besides that, you shouldn't operate on the `ItemsSource` property of an ItemsControl (as you seem to be doing). Instead, change the source property (i.e. the property that ItemsSource was bound to).

Comment: @Clemens No, thats not true because `ICollection<T>` does not support covariance (it must not)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an element to a newly created list. `List<T>` does not forward any newly added elements to any other collection, so you have to add your element to the original collection.

There are two possibilities, either you know the type of your objects or you don't.

If you do, cast your `IEnumerable` to `ICollection<ElementType>` and use the Add method.

```
((ICollection<T>)ItemsSource).Add(NewItemsSourceAppointment)
```

If you don't, there is a good chance that the collection still implements the non-generic `IList` interface. You can cast to that and call Add there.

```
((IList)ItemsSource).Add(NewItemsSourceAppointment)
```

For most collection interfaces, the latter is fine.

However, it may also be that none of the above works, that's when your ItemsSource collection is read-only, as for example the result of a Select call.

**Edit:** This is going to add your element to the collection. Whether or not the collection is going to fire a collection changed event is up to the collection implementation.